# Passing a C# DateTime via the Query String

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a C# DateTime object. This object includes both the date and time. I need to pass this information to a REST-based service. My question is, how do I format the DateTime, such that I can pass it via the query string, and parse it back into a DateTime on the server-side?

```
DateTime startDate = GetStartDate();
string url = "http://www.mydomain.com/myservice.svc/[startDateGoesHere]

WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Service_Completed), request);
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just use ToString() and pass a format e.g.:

```
startDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

And parse it back by using [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact was 'exactly' what I needed.  No pun intended.  Thanks!

Comment: Consider using startDate.Ticks and new DateTime(ticks) also

Answer (score 29):

For accuracy and consistency you could use:

```
string utcDateOut = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime utcDateIn = DateTime.ParseExact(utcDateOut, "s", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                              DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

This will give you an ISO 8601 compliant format and the use of UTC will ensure that there are no issues with time zones etc.

Only drawback is that it doesn't look as "nice" as a simple "yyyyMMdd".

Answer (score 7):

I'd use `yyyyMMdd` as the format; doesn't need to be URL encoded and it's easy to read/understand.

On the server side, you'd have to call `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd")` to get the date out.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

string s = `DateTime`.**ToString**("*yyyyMMddHHmmssfff*")
Note: fff is milliseconds (you may remove the 'fff' if it is not needed)
Then convert it back to DateTime using
DateTime d = `DateTime`.**ParseExact**(s, "*yyyyMMddHHmmssfff*", `CultureInfo`.**InvariantCulture**)

Answer (score 1):

For those wanting to create a date/time in UTC and then have your web api consume it and be aware of UTC as the DateTime kind you can do:

```
var startDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24).ToString("u",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will output your date time as:

> 2023-12-07 10:47:04Z

The Z here will be used to convey the datetime is in UTC format. Then on your consuming API, for example:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

It will then parse the DateTime in the correct format with the DateTime kind as UTC.

Hope that helps :)