# Wrong formatting of DateTime from QueryString

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, asp.net-core

On my page I have a form for filtering a list of machines. The form posts with GET method.
Two of the fields in that form are text fields for entering a date.

Based on the inputs in the form, I'm filtering the list. My problem is, that the date filtering doesn't work as expected.

The dates are entered in the format dd/MM/yyyy. The system CultureInfo is "da-DK".
Dates are stored i MSSQL as yyyy-MM-dd.

I have this filter model:

```
public class MachineFilter
{

    [DisplayName("Search")]
    public string Search { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Installation date, from")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? InstallationDateFrom { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Installation date, to")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? InstallationDateTo { get; set; }

}
```

And the filtering (simplified):

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public MachineFilter MachineFilter { get; set; }

----

Machines = await _dbContext.Machines.ToListAsync();

if (MachineFilter.InstallationDateFrom != null)
{
    Machines = Machines.Where(x => x.InstallationDate != null && x.InstallationDate >= MachineFilter.InstallationDateFrom).ToList();
}
```

In this example two things can happen: 1) the filtering isn't applied - or 2) wrong results returns to the list.

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929471/passing-a-c-sharp-datetime-via-the-query-string) I also tried converting the input to string and back to DateTime with DateTime.ParseExact:

```
string dateFrom = MachineFilter.InstallationDateFrom?.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(dateFrom, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Machines = Machines.Where(x => x.InstallationDate != null && x.InstallationDate >= dFrom).ToList();
```

But no matter what I do, I end up with a wrong DateTime format, so entering 01/12/2019 (dd/MM/yyyy) becomes 01/12/2019 (MM/dd/yyyy).

Right now the culture is only "da-DK", so I could do some splitting of the posted input and add a new DateTime(yyyy, MM, dd) of the array, but soon the system will scale to other countries and then dates will be entered as MM/dd/yyyy, so I'd like a more "build-in" approach if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is from a web-page, then you can use the standard javascript iso date-format with standard MVC date binders, as per my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699851/convert-javascript-date-to-net-datetime/30184408#30184408

You should also postpone the .ToListAsync() to after the .Where - statements. I can put this in an answer, if you think I understood the situation correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's no javascript in this part.

Comment: What's your front-end? An MVC razor page?

Comment: Yes, .NET Core with Razor pages.

Comment: Are you using the standard razor method for GET-forms?
@using (Html.BeginForm("mySearchAction", "myController", FormMethod.Get, null))

Comment: In believe I've solved it myself. In my filter model I changed InstalledFromDate/InstalledToDate to string and just do DateTime.Parse on the string posted. Sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to my problem was to set the model types to `string` instead of `DateTime` and in my filter parse them to `DateTime`, like:

```
[DisplayName("Installation date, from")]
public string InstallationDateFrom { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Installation date, to")]
public string InstallationDateTo { get; set; }
```

--

```
Machines = Machines.Where(x => x.InstallationDate != null && x.InstallationDate >= DateTime.Parse(MachineFilter.InstallationDateFrom)).ToList();
```